# ClassCastException when trying to unparcel a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: android, serialization, classcastexception, parcelable, parcel

I encountered some strange behavior when working with `ConcurrentHashMap` and androids parcel mechanism.

My situation is, I have an ConcurrentHashMap which is parceled at some point. I do it the recommended way by serializing it to a Bundle and then writing the bundle to the parcel:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, CustomClass> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

...

@Override
public void writeToParcel ( Parcel dest, int flags ) {      
    Bundle map = new Bundle(1);
    map.putSerializable("map", concurrentMap);
    dest.writeBundle(map);
}
```

I retrieve it later on like this:

```
public void readFromParcel ( Parcel in ) {

    Bundle map = in.readBundle(CustomClass.class.getClassLoader());
    concurrentMap = (ConcurrentHashMap<String, CustomClass>) map.getSerializable("map");  
}
```

The **ClassCastException** happens at the last line when trying to cast the retrieved Map back to the `ConcurrentHashMap`.
Since both HashMap and `ConcurrentHashMap` implement the `Serializable` interface and extend `AbstractMap` I don't really understand this issue.

Has somebody experienced this too or can explain this issue?

Comment: your custom class should also implement serializable interface

Comment: The custom class implements Parcelable. What I forgot to mention is, that if I change the type of concurrentMap to HashMap it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this is no explanation but at least there is a quick fix for me. I don't like it but it works.

Since 'getSerializable()' somehow treats my ConcurrentHashMap as a normal HashMap, I temporally use a HashMap to get my ConcurrentHashMap.

```
 HashMap<String, CustomClass > tempMap = (HashMap<String, CustomClass >) map.getSerializable("map");
 concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(tempMap);
```